# How to use Count() without counting the duplicated value in different rows in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named Review.
It contains reviews given by the customers on the cleaning companies that they have been experienced before.
The same ReviewerID can give many reviews on the same company(anytime).
1 ReviewerID == 1 person.
I decided to make every review to have a ReviewID as each review will have a different review_statement.
So, the ReviewID is the PK and companyID is the FK.

```
reviewID | reviewerID | companyID | Statement
  001    |   James216 |  clean417 | "different statement"
  002    |   James216 |  clean417 | "different statement"
  003    |   Lee_216  |  clean417 | "different statement"
```

I want to obtain the number of companies reviewed by each ReviewerID in the database.
By refering the table, the desired output is `James216 1` (1 because James216 only reviewed company clean417). I've tried using COUNT but it will count the non-null row,causing the output to be `James216 2`.

I've also tried using select distinct but the output wont be correct.
I seriously cant figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> In any aggregate function that takes a single argument, that argument can be preceded by the keyword DISTINCT.

You can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(YourField) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't think it supports `count(distinct)`, you can solve it by creating a unique subset:

```
select reviewerID, count(companyID) 
  from (select distinct reviewerID, companyID
          from Review)
 group by reviewerID;
```

Comment: is select distinct equal to select? @user212514

Comment: No, it's not the same.  `select distinct` will give you only one row for James216/clean417 rather than the two rows that are in the actual table.